# Что такое "ахинея"?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Часто встречается фраза: "несёт ахинею", означающая: говорит глупость, чушь. Интересно узнать, что означает слово "ахинея", и откуда это высказывание пришло в язык?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этимология слова "ахинея" не считается ясной, его происхождение связывают с разными версиями:

1. Ахинея восходит к Афенея - название храма Афины, где происходили философские диспуты, затем произошло переосмысление "лженаучные прения - чушь, вздор".
2. Существует южное диалектное слово "хинь" - чушь, вздор, чепуха, хинить - бранить, хулить. Также существовал топоним Хинь - названия Китая (ещё у Державина - поляк, перс, прусс, хин). И здесь можно вспомнить о непонятной "китайской грамоте".

Answer (score 0):

Вот что говорит В.Даль:
ХИНИТЬ что, сев. хулить, хаять, охуждать, бранить, бол. охинить. **Хинь** ж. орл. кур. яросл. **ахинея, гиль, чушь, чепуха, вздор, пустяки. Такую хинь занес, что уши вянут!** У него все хинью пошло, даром, на ветер, без пользы и толку.